# Plot single 3D point and surface into one figure

Tags: matlab

I just want to plot a surface and a single point into one figure. But it isn't working unfortunately. In addition, i want to keep the axis limits I've specified.

Thank you for any help!

mldmnn

```
%% Create Observer Grid

[obsX obsY] = meshgrid(0:1:50); % Generate X and Y data of the observer positions

obsZ = zeros(size(obsX, 1)); % Generate Z data of the observer positions (always with obsZ = 0)

obsPos = [obsX(:), obsY(:), obsZ(:)]; % List every observer position

%% Read Source Position

% Dummy source position

srcX = 10;
srcY= 10;
srcZ = 25;
srcPos = [srcX srcY srcZ]; 

%% For the Sake of Visualisation: Plot Observer Plane and Source Position

surf (obsX, obsY, obsZ);
plot3(srcX, srcY, srcZ,'.r','MarkerSize', 30);
xlim([0 50]);
ylim([0 srcY+15]);
zlim([0 50]);
grid on;
```

Comment: add [`hold on`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html) between `surf` and `plot3`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [`hold on`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html) method to retain plots in the current axes so that new plots added to the axes do not delete existing plots. So, you need to make some modifications of your code snippet:

```
surf (obsX, obsY, obsZ);
hold on;
plot3(srcX, srcY, srcZ,'.r','MarkerSize', 30);
xlim([0 50]);
ylim([0 srcY+15]);
zlim([0 50]);
grid on;
hold off;
```

Comment: @mldmnn , I'm glad ;)